# Is it already possible to enable Compiz on an i5 Thinkpad laptop?

Tags: 10.10, compiz, graphics, thinkpad, intel

Besides a number of other issues, I still cannot enable Compiz or any effects with Maverick on a Thinkpad X201. I understand this laptop is supported by Ubuntu, yet I have found a good number of posts reporting problems. I would like to know if they have been solved by now.

> Processor: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 540 @ 2.53GHz
>
> Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
>
> OpenGL Renderer Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT
>
> 2.6.35-27-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP

Here are further details on some of the failures after another clean install:

> [...] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to get i915 symbols, graphics turbo disabled
>
> [...] pulseaudio[1550]: module.c: Failed to load  module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="29" name="platform-thinkpad_acpi" card_name="alsa_card.platform-thinkpad_acpi" tsched=yes ignore_dB=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
>
> [...] gdm-session-worker[1542]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_value_get_boolean: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_BOOLEAN (value)' failed
>
> [...] No AGP bridge found
>
> [...] NetworkManager[1089]: supplicant_interface_acquire: assertion `mgr_state == NM_SUPPLICANT_MANAGER_STATE_IDLE' failed
>
> [...] 1.065116] PM: Resume from disk failed.

Comment: I have the same machine and have no problems with Compiz; although am having some display issues with apps under Wine.

Comment: Hi. Don't you have any issues with the integrated Intel HD Graphics? I've had problems with it on a Thinkpad X201 3626 since the very beginnig, with a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10. Could you please let me know how do you have it configured?

Comment: I merged your accounts and pulled your additional information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain as the proud owner of a T510 with i915. I had way too many freezes to be
productive, and this was 10.04. I ended up disabling compiz completely, and eventually installed Enlightenment which was much more stable and faster.

So how does this help you? I type this post on an Acer aspire one D255E which is using i915 on Natty and have not encountered a single graphics issue, all the eye candy works, it's responsive, no hangs, no nothing. Suspend/Resume is fine but there's minor graphics glitch with hibernate, I can live with that.

So give Natty a try, you might find that your graphics trouble have gone away. Barring that, you should be able to install the Natty kernel on Maverick via backports. That could help things. I don't know about a backports for Xorg, I presume that's alot of extra packaging work. Hope that helps.